# Google Big Query Traces vs Transactions

Tags: chaindata

Doing some work on google bigquery ethereum data and am a bit confused by traces vs transactions. It seems that transactions are a subset of traces? with more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transaction are what is called “transaction” in Ethereum, i.e. real transactions sent from externally owned addresses and included into blocks.

Traces seem to be (very close to) what [Etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) calls "internal transactions", i.e. anything that may potentially transfer ether or control flow from one address to another, excluding transactions.  Possible trace types are: `call`, `create`, `suicide`, `reward`, `genesis`, `daofork`.